# Developing a Portlet with Multiple Actions in Liferay

Tags: liferay

There is a guide on the Liferay site [Developing a Portlet with Multiple Actions](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/developing-a-portlet-with-multiple-actions)

Do you know where I should place the code of the MyGreetingPortlet class?

What should be the file name and in which folder I should place it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Anatomy of a portlet](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/anatomy-of-a-portlet) in the same tutorial.

Comment: Thanks MAKKAM. But I still have a problem. You define your portlet class using <portlet-class> tag in your portlet.xml file. For example if I write this tag as <portlet-class>com.liferay.portlet</portlet-class> I must have a package called "com.liferay.portlet" in my src folder and I can write java codes in that package. But when it is like "<portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>" where should I place my java codes?

Comment: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet is a base class for portlet included in the liferay standard library. In the tutorial above they use <portlet-class>com.liferay.samples.MyGreetingPortlet</portlet-class> which means that there is a package named "com.liferay.samples" containing class named "MyGreetingPortlet". Usually source code placed in the "/docroot/WEB-INF/src/com/liferay/samples/MyGreetingPortlet.java" path in file system.

Comment: I created a package called "com.liferay.samples" and I put "MyGreetingPortlet.java" class in it. Then I deployed th portlet. But When I go to edit page and hit the save button it shows "Portlet is temporarily unavailable" message.

Comment: Look for detailed error description in application server log files.

Comment: This is the error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.setGreeting(javax.portlet.ActionRequest, javax.portlet.ActionResponse)"

Comment: Double check your configuration files. Are you sure that you have `<portlet-class>com.liferay.samples.MyGreetingPortlet</portlet-class>` in your portlet.xml file? It seems to me that MVCPortlet specified as a portlet class.

Comment: Thanks default locale. Now it is ok.